# updating a div partial in rails after submitting form via javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i have a table named whatsup, and also users, and its implemented in such a way that whatsup belongs to user, 
 i have made it possible for users to create whatsups via ajax like this

```
$("#chat").append("<%= j render(@whatsup) %>");
$("#new_whatsup")[0].reset();
```

and i display the whatsups created untop of the form like this

```
<ul id="chat">
  <%= render @whatsups %>
</ul>

<%= form_for Whatsup.new, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :details%>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller @whatsups is declared like this

```
@whatsups = current_user.whatsups.all(:limit => 1, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

which means one whatsup should be displayed at a time

what i want is, the partial @whatsups should be reloaded immediately the form is submitted without reloading the entire page i.e reloading that div alone so that the new whatsups created will be shown automatically.

Comment: Is the line `@whatsups = current_user.whatsups.all(:limit => 1, :order => 'created_at DESC')` from your `create` action?

Comment: nope, its in my Users show action

Comment: in that case do you have `_whatsup.html.erb`?

Comment: yes i  have that template too

Comment: Please post your `_whatsup.html.erb`.  The problem could be there if you are not seeing the result.

Comment: <i class="right" style="margin-bottom: -20px; font-size: 14px;">
              <p>" <%= whatsup.details %>"</p>

            </i>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a js response in your create action, like this:

In WhatsupsController#create do:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

Then create the view file views/whatsups/create.js.erb. There you can create a JavaScript that will be executed on the page when the create has finished. Something like that:

```
$("#chat").append("<%= j render(@whatsup) %>");
```